# What's a good place for getting answers on software from Progress?

Tags: discussion, views, popularity

As you can see from [my profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4279155/dominique), I'm already on this site for several years now, mostly working on UNIX/Linux, Excel, C++, and Java questions.

Recently I have joined a firm where I'm working with the [OpenEdge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progress_Software#Product) programming environment from [Progress Software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progress_Software), and as a newly starting programmer in this new environment, I start off with quite some questions, like those three ones:

- [First question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65337310/progress-newbie-question-where-are-the-error-codes)
- [Second question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65353618/how-to-perform-basic-string-handling-in-progress)
- [Third question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65355867/how-to-avoid-thousand-separator-in-fill-in-basic-component)

I got a correct answer to my first question, but the two other ones are still waiting for an answer.

When looking at the number of views, this reveals a lot:

```
First question   30 views
Second question  12 views
Third question    9 views
```

This clearly shows a lack of popularity of the "Progress" tag I've used for asking those questions. I already checked two other discussion fora ([Quora](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quora) and [Reddit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reddit)), but there the situation seems to be worse.

What can I do in order to get more views, and as a direct result, quicker answers on OpenEdge-related questions?

Should I ask my questions on another site (in that case, which one)? Or should I add other tags to my questions (in that case, which ones)?

Comment: If anything, measured by votes, there is no reduced lack of popularity: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1349722#graph

Answer (score 9):

Questions about Progress software are definitely on-topic on Stack Overflow.

Looking through your questions, they seem to be well-articulated, as well as properly formatted and tagged. I don't think the issue is with the questions themselves, but with the lack of popularity of the subject matter, at least here of Stack Overflow - e.g., no user even [has a bronze badge for this tag](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1349720/progress-badges), as opposed to popular languages like Java or C# (more than 7K users with bronze badges, and about a tenth of those with gold badges).

I can't think of a more appropriate Stack Exchange site for those questions, unfortunately.

Comment: So, as you say (and this seems to be confirmed by Rene, showing that there are about 700 questions on that subject over a period of several years) the StackExchange network is not well suited for OpenEdge Progress questions. Are you aware of other sites (besides Quora and Reddit, which seem even worse than the StackExchange network for this) who might be more appropriate for those questions?

Comment: TBH, I never even heard about Progress before I saw your question

Comment: I never heard about Progress before I applied for a job in that firm :-)

Comment: @Dominique: Stack Overflow was ***explicitly*** designed to (also) work for obscure topics. The founders talked about this in the first series of the podcast. It works for [Forth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/forth) (245 questions over 12 years (an average of a question every 18 days)), so it could also work for OpenEdge.

Comment: In the meantime, I've discovered another issue: the name "Progress" is chosen really bad for a programming language. As a result, people with questions about progressbars and the progress of the execution of their programs are also adding "[progress]" tag to their question. I've replaced this tag by "[progress-4gl]" and "[OpenEdge]" tags in order to get more attention by the right people.

Comment: @PeterMortensen: I've manually removed the "[Progress]" tag from some questions, not about "Progress" OpenEdge, but there seem so many of them that I can't this for all wrong ones. Is there a way to do this automatically, remove this tag and replace it by "[progress-4gl]" and make sure this wrongly used "[progress]" tag does not get recreated again?